# When will I unlock every tool in New Pokémon Snap?

Tags: new-pokemon-snap

Trying to keep it spoiler free.

I'm currently waiting to basically have all tools at my disposal before going back to regions so I know when I do runs, I have everything needed to figure out the puzzles.

So except for the Lumina balls, at what point in the story would I know that I've got every tool the game will ever give me to get new Pokemon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Batophobia stated in comments, you can check which features have yet to be unlocked by viewing your controller settings. Anything with "???" has not been unlocked.

With that said, aside from the Illumina Orbs, as they are unlocked at various times in each Island, you should have all the NEO-ONE tools unlocked after completing the first 4 Illumina routes, and unlocking the 5th Island ([Source](https://game8.co/games/New-Pokemon-Snap/archives/329742)).

All but one of the NEO-ONE features are unlocked early on in the game, and the feature that is unlocked after finishing the requirements above is:

> The Turbo feature, which allows you to speed up the NEO-ONE to navigate through the map more quickly.

After finishing the main story, and returning to the lab after the credit, a new feature (though not NEO-ONE specific) and can be enabled or disabled through the settings

> Burst Mode. If enabled, you can take either 3, 4, or 6 photos with a single click. If disabled, it defaults to a single photo

Comment: I had my doubts that was the last upgrade, since its the same as the original Pokemon Snap